# Is there a tool to generate a React UI from an OpenAPI specification?

Tags: reactjs, swagger-ui, openapi

I'd like to generate an "out of the box, customer facing" (within reason!) React UI from an OpenAPI specification - here is my shopping list of nice-to-haves:

- Show a list of API entities with some sort of hierarchy where they are related
- Clicking on an entity would display a *paged*, *sortable*, *filterable* grid for that entity
- Basic UI for adding/editing new entity complete with type editors/validation for each entity property
- Allowing for styling/logic customisations whilst still allowing re-generation of the UI

I am aware of the Swagger UI project and even the [React version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-react), but it generates a [very tech-centric output](https://petstore.swagger.io/) which is great for experimenting with the API but not quite what I am after here in terms of a customer-facing application - perhaps it can be customised, or does anyone know of alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know apart from [swagger-ui-react](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/flavors/swagger-ui-react) you have another solid option here that is [stoplight-elements](https://docs.stoplight.io/docs/elements/b5f929847c884-getting-started-with-elements-in-react):

```js
import React from 'react';

import { API } from '@stoplight/elements';
import '@stoplight/elements/styles.min.css';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <API
        apiDescriptionUrl="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stoplightio/Public-APIs/master/reference/zoom/openapi.yaml"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It's a pretty good solution (we're currently using it in one of our projects) to render OAS files using JSON strings. It currently works for both React and Nextjs apps and in order to customize you could import the main CSS an edited as you like.